# Can't get proper coordinate out of linear function

Tags: python, math, coordinates, line, polyline

What i'm doing right now is regrouping bezier curve and line's 100 coordinate points into a single polyline, for this purpose, i'm trying to use math to generate the coordinate of the points placed on a line between 1 start and 1 end point.

The issue is that i'm getting either correct y value, higher y value and lower y value than expected depending on the case on a straight line (bezier work fine), here is my code right now:

```py
import pygame
from pygame import gfxdraw
from random import randint
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from time import time
import math
import numpy as np

width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)

def generate_original_points_coordinates(circle_size_px):
    generating = True
    while generating:
        x = randint(0,width)
        y = randint(0,height)
        if y < height-circle_size_px and y > circle_size_px and x < width-circle_size_px and x > circle_size_px:
            points.append([x, y])
            generating = False

def generate_points_coordinates(count, spacing, circle_size_px):
    for i in range(0,count-1):
        generating = True
        while generating:
            x = points[-1][0]+randint(-spacing,spacing)
            y = points[-1][1]+randint(-spacing,spacing)
            if y < height-circle_size_px and y > circle_size_px and x < width-circle_size_px and x > circle_size_px: 
                generating = False
                points.append([x, y])
        
def generate_original_and_p(count, spacing, circle_size_px):
    generate_original_points_coordinates(circle_size_px)
    generate_points_coordinates(count, spacing, circle_size_px)
    return points

running = True
while running:
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    text = font.render('NotBezier', True, (0,0,255))
    points = []
    gen_points = generate_original_and_p(9,800,234)
    size = [width, height]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size,0,32)
    screen.fill((33,33,33))
    curve = []
    # Draw bezier curves from points in a list
    for i in range(0,len(gen_points)-2):
        dist_s = math.sqrt(math.pow(gen_points[i+2][0]-gen_points[i][0],2)+math.pow(gen_points[i+2][1]-gen_points[i][1],2))
        dist_x = gen_points[i+2][0] - gen_points[i][0]
        dist_y = gen_points[i+2][1] - gen_points[i][1]
        if dist_s < 234/2:
            line = []
            print(dist_s)
            gfxdraw.line(screen,gen_points[i][0], gen_points[i][1], gen_points[i+2][0], gen_points[i+2][1],(0,0,255))
            m = (gen_points[i][1] - gen_points[i+2][1]) / (gen_points[i][0] - gen_points[i+2][0])
            b = np.linalg.norm(np.diff([gen_points[i],gen_points[i+2]], axis=0), axis=1).tolist()[0]
            for ratio in np.linspace(0,1,10):
                print("ratio = "+str(ratio)+", m = "+str(m)+", b = "+str(b)+", dist_x = "+str(dist_x)+", dist_y = "+str(dist_y))
                line.append([gen_points[i][0]+(ratio * dist_x), gen_points[i][1] + (m * (ratio * dist_y) + b)])
            curve.append(line)
        if i+2 == len(gen_points)-1:
            gfxdraw.filled_circle(screen, gen_points[i+2][0], gen_points[i+2][1],5,(0,255,0))
            screen.blit(font.render(str(i+2), True, (0,255,0)), (gen_points[i+2][0],gen_points[i+2][1]+10))
        gfxdraw.filled_circle(screen, gen_points[i][0], gen_points[i][1],5,(0,255,0))
        screen.blit(font.render(str(i), True, (0,255,0)), (gen_points[i][0],gen_points[i][1]+10))

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Place points on such curves and lines

    print(gen_points)
    print(curve)
    print(len(curve))
    i = input("quit?: ")
    pygame.display.quit()
    if i == "quit":
        running = False
```

This is an example list of points [[1059, 559], [1472, 684], [1090, 509]]

Here is an example output in case a line is created:

```
ratio = 0.0, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.1111111111111111, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.2222222222222222, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.3333333333333333, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.4444444444444444, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.5555555555555556, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.6666666666666666, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.7777777777777777, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 0.8888888888888888, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50
ratio = 1.0, m = -1.6129032258064515, b = 58.83026432033091, dist_x = 31, dist_y = -50

# Points on screen

[
    [807, 333], 
    [1205, 526], 
    [1257, 373], 
    [1039, 507], 
    [724, 834], 
    [626, 765], 
    [1059, 559], 
    [1472, 684], 
    [1090, 509]
]

# Coordinate of the 10 points located on that line and spaced by 10%

[
    [
         [1059.0, 617.8302643203309], 
         [1062.4444444444443, 626.7908377970334], 
         [1065.888888888889, 635.7514112737359], 
         [1069.3333333333333, 644.7119847504384], 
         [1072.7777777777778, 653.6725582271409], 
         [1076.2222222222222, 662.6331317038434], 
         [1079.6666666666667, 671.593705180546], 
         [1083.111111111111, 680.5542786572485], 
         [1086.5555555555557, 689.514852133951], 
         [1090.0, 698.4754256106535]
     ]
]
```

As you can see, the y abscissa using this function is higher than expected, and that only a case from many.

Any idea on what's causing this issue and how to fix it?

TL:DR -> obtaining incorrect y value for some cases with thisis function https://pastebin.com/xgNLQiVt

Comment: Can you reduce your giant example to a single case that reproduces the error?

Comment: Please follow this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I haven't voted to close this because you've clearly put some effort into understanding and debugging the issue, but your presentation needs a bit more focus. We don't need to see your whole code base. Just a standalone runnable example with the exact same error.

Comment: Only the line part is left, but the code that seemed not important to you was removed and the code left will of course have errors if anyone try to use it, i'll will keep my coordinates there as it is.

Comment: Sure. How do I run it? Those are just function definitions.

Comment: Thanks for actually responding. I usually see beginners dump a bunch of code and make no effort to improve their question after.

Comment: I think we're still at cross purposes here. You don't need to show me user interaction. Just pick a value and hard code it. I don't need to see the full program. Please read the MCVE link and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If i did my job correctly, everything should be working with just a copy paste, though it's possible i missed some stuff, but i tried it now and it work on my side so i hope it work for other who want to try and fix it somehow. 
Also i've been debugging this specific issue for about 3h without finding the cause.
i know this is supposed to be simple math, but again, can't figure it out.

Comment: If you're not sure that you example runs and generates the error, then you should be testing it out, not us

Comment: i've tried different equitation, functions, library for this, and it's still doing the same, i've fixed b not calculating properly before that but i can't figure out how to get the proper y while, testing is the first thing i do, i'm not stupid enough to just throw code at people without testing it in the first place, i've done my fair share of edits and trick in values and  found no solutions to my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it's complicated for 50K+ to provide the usage of a certain function knowing that i also use numpy in my code, i found another way to get what i was looking for:

```py
#  Generate 1000 x coordinates / Generate 1000 y coordinates

list_x, list_y = np.linspace(Points[i][0],Points[i+2][0],1000), np.linspace(Points[i][1],Points[i+2][1],1000)

#  Generate a list of coordinates out of list_x and list_y

line = [[list_x[i],list_y[i]] for i in range(1000)]
```

and there is probably an even easier and shorter way that i don't know to obtain the same thing